# TransceiveResult return response null with sony Xperia

Tags: java, android, tags, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to read a MifareClassic card by NFC. In a Samsung cellphone, the process works fine. But when I try execute the same process in a sony cellphone don't work.

```
byte[] transceive(byte[] data, boolean raw) throws IOException {
    checkConnected();

    try {
        TransceiveResult result =       mTag.getTagService().transceive(mTag.getServiceHandle(),
                data, raw);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IOException("transceive failed");
        } else {
            return result.getResponseOrThrow();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NFC service dead", e);
        throw new IOException("NFC service died");
    }
}
```

The diference between the two cases (the image below) is what the tag function "transcieve" return to me. In the Samsung return response with value, but in the Sony, return null value. Why this function return diferent results in diferent cellphones to the same card?

[image]

Comment: What's the exact model name of your sony phone? Some simply don't support Mifare tags.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck the Sony that I'm testing is the Sony Xperia E3 D2243

Comment: Well, this list: http://www.shopnfc.it/en/content/7-nfc-device-compatibility does list support for the Experia E3. How does your code work with other android phones and how does the data look like that you're trying to transceive?

Comment: Thank you @NilsPipenbrinck ! Well, I put a image in this post that show what return in each case (in Samsung and in the Sony). In the case of Sony, that return null value, show me an exception with the phrase: "Tag was lost"